# Chrome extensione gent result from div

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to build a chrome extensione that was able to get a value from the current opened page (the value is inside a grid/table) and make some calculation on that.

I can get the value with this js command:

```
document.getElementById("dgrid_2-row-0").getElementsByClassName("dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-column-0 field-field1").item(0).innerText
```

But if I run in on simply extension with a popup I can't get the value because was in another page, this is why I follow background and chrome example tutorial to build this architecture.

**backgound.js**

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    console.log('Injecting content script(s)');
    //On Firefox document.body.textContent is probably more appropriate
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{
        code: '(function (){return document.getElementById("dgrid_2-row-0").getElementsByClassName("dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-column-0 field-field1").item(0).innerText})();'
    },receiveText);
});

function receiveText(resultsArray){
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('foo');
    //console.log(resultsArray[0]);
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "action": {        
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "test" },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

**index.html** An empty table to use when I'm able to get the result...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>I Have To Go Out!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-3" style="width: 450px;">
        <h2 class="text-center">Report</h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Entrance</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Confirmed</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="date"></td>
                <td id="areaName"></td>
                <td id="latestBy"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All seems works fine because I don't have error when I run it but I have two problems, the first is that I can't see anything logged on console, also inspecting the console of the exstension, and the second one, that I can't understand, how I can get the return value and use it on the index.html??

My idea was I can add another script on index.html, loaded by

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

and use the result from background to add some value. Can you help me with some advide or linking an example?

**EDIT after few comments:**
I have changed the index.html to run script.js when opened

**script.js**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{
    code: 'alert('"test"')';
});
```

but I can't see the test message. If I change script.js to

```
alert('test')
```

I have the "test" message. If, instead of the alert, I set something like

```
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

the HTML table background color became blue but this is not I looking for, becuase I want to get value from document on opened Chrome tab. What I misunderstood?

Comment: The `chrome.action.onClicked.addListener` listener will not be called if you have a popup window set (which you do based on the manifest). Yes, the way to go is to add a script to the popup window and inject the script into the page from there.

Comment: How can I get the value that I looking for from the popup script?

Comment: The same as you do now from the background service worker. When the popup script is executed, it means that the extension's icon was clicked and the popup window was opened. If you don't specify a tab id when you call `chrome.tabs.executeScript(..)`, the script will be injected into the active tab, [example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/activeTab/#example)

Comment: Sorry, not clear for me. I did it but nothing changes. First I have added to call "script.js" in the index.html. But when I click on button, I can't see any at console, look at the screen... what happend? https://i.imgur.com/Us2foIH.png

Comment: You'll have to modify the script, use just `chrome.tabs.executeScript(..)` don't add that inside `chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {..})`

Comment: Nothing change, In my script.js I simply add 
"chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{
    code: 'alert('"test"')'
});" but nothing changed. Also if I add an "alert("Hello!") without chrome.tabs.executeScript I can see the message... It's seems like the function chrome.tabs.executeScript does't work on script.js...

Comment: Use just `chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'alert('"test"')' });` without the `tab.id` like I've mentioned in one of my previous comments. Also, to see the pop-up's console. Right click the extension's icon and select **Inspect pop-up** from the menu.

Comment: 'chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'alert('"test"')' });' did't work. When I inspect the popup I have an "Unxecspected string" error; I have tried to add an ; or change the ' or " but nothing changed... some on internet says to use the chrome.scripting.executeScript for manifest v3 but also that not work for me...

Comment: Yes, it will be a good idea to use MV3 at this point but still, if you get that error, you probably have some syntax error in the script that you add to the popup window. In any case, you should post a new question or edit this question to reflect the changes that you made and the error that you get because, at this point, I'm not sure what is going on. Also, if you still want my help (even though I haven't fixed this yet) just add a comment to this question with @Titus

Comment: @Tidus I wrote exactly (and only) the code you wrote. I can avoid the error only if remove the ' in the string and write the code like that     "chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: alert(' "test" ') });"    but, after see the alert, I have the error that "executeScript is not a function". In any case, the question remain the same one I wrote; also with your suggestion (thank you!), I can't interact with page and the opened tab, until now; if instead of alert I write code for change background color of the document I still change/get only info of the popup, not to the open and active chrome tab.